# Angular 7 and angular material changing row color of datasource table when its checked by a checkbox is allowing one row to be colored

Tags: angular, datasource, angular7, angular-material-6

I need to add a checkbox to material table showing multiple rows of data and if a user checked it, the full row should change color to a green or something else.

having this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-borrea), if a user selects one row, it will turn green, and if he selected another one, the previous will turn off, and the new will be colored.

I used this function to get the id of the row:

```
changeColor(id)
   {
     this.coloredRow = id;
   }
```

And here is my material datasource table:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSorActive="unit_date_added" disableClear matSortDirection="asc"
    *ngIf="!showSpinner">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>

      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"  (click)="changeColor(row.location_id_auto)" >
        <mat-checkbox>
        </mat-checkbox>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="hh_id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>HH ID</th>
      <td class="alignTd" mat-header *matCellDef="let row">{{row.hh_id}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="unit_id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>UNIT ID</th>
      <td class="alignTd" mat-header *matCellDef="let row">{{row.uid}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name_en">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Unit Type</th>
      <td mat-header *matCellDef="let row">{{row.name_en}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="location_id_auto">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
      <td mat-header *matCellDef="let row">{{row.location_id_auto}}</td>
    </ng-container>



    <tr class="example-expanded-row mat-column-name" mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr class="mat-column-name" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; let i = index; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="{'highlight2': coloredRow == row.location_id_auto}">

    </tr>
  </table>
```

And the css style:

```
.highlight2{
     background: #42A948; /* green */
   }
```

The current behavior is that only one row's color will be changed.

Comment: First of all why you using checkboxes? You can just use the `(click)="coloredRow = i"` and `[ngClass]="{'highlight2': coloredRow == i}"`

Comment: I need to color multiple rows, and a user should be able to uncheck a row to remove the color

Comment: Hmm you can try `(click)="row.color = !row.color"` and  `[ngClass]="{'highlight2': row.color }"`

Answer (score 2):

You want more than one row can change color? change your code to this:
in the HTML:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSorActive="unit_date_added" disableClear matSortDirection="asc"
    *ngIf="!showSpinner">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>

      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"   >
        <mat-checkbox>
        </mat-checkbox>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="hh_id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>HH ID</th>
      <td class="alignTd" mat-header *matCellDef="let row">{{row.hh_id}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="unit_id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>UNIT ID</th>
      <td class="alignTd" mat-header *matCellDef="let row">{{row.uid}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name_en">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Unit Type</th>
      <td mat-header *matCellDef="let row">{{row.name_en}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="location_id_auto">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
      <td mat-header *matCellDef="let row">{{row.location_id_auto}}</td>
    </ng-container>



    <tr class="example-expanded-row mat-column-name" mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr class="mat-column-name" mat-row (click)="changeColor(i)" *matRowDef="let row; index as i; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="{'highlight2': coloredRow[i] == true}">

    </tr>
  </table>
```

int the ts:

```
coloredRow:boolean[]=[];
changeColor(index)
  {
    this.coloredRow[index] =!this.coloredRow[index];
  }
```

Comment: There is only one single problem. When I go through pages in data table, and if I was selecting row index 1, at the next page, the first row will be highlighted too as it has 1 as index because it's in the second page

Answer (score 1):

Ideally I think you want to track whether the row is checked or not in your data array / your model. I modified your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-4xotbd) with an additional property `checked` which gets set via the checkbox and upon which the coloring of the row is based.

The `checked` property is set via two-way data binding using ngModel:

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="row.checked"></mat-checkbox>
```

Setting the color of the row is as before, just use the `checked` property of the current row:

```
<tr class="mat-column-name" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; let i = index; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="{'highlight2': row.checked}">
```

Comment: Is there a way, other than using `[(ngModel)]` ? That's exactly what I want, but I don't want to import `FormsModule`.

Comment: There is: `<mat-checkbox [checked]="row.checked" (change)="row.checked = !row.checked"></mat-checkbox>`. Even though I would suggest that you use ngModel as this is how the `MatCheckbox` is used in the examples over at https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/examples

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution.

Ive based it in this link also in https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Here's the code:

app.component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSorActive="unit_date_added" disableClear matSortDirection="asc"
    *ngIf="!showSpinner">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>

      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"  (click)="changeColor(row.location_id_auto)" >
        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"> 
        </mat-checkbox>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="hh_id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>HH ID</th>
      <td class="alignTd" mat-header *matCellDef="let row">{{row.hh_id}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="unit_id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>UNIT ID</th>
      <td class="alignTd" mat-header *matCellDef="let row">{{row.uid}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name_en">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Unit Type</th>
      <td mat-header *matCellDef="let row">{{row.name_en}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="location_id_auto">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
      <td mat-header *matCellDef="let row">{{row.location_id_auto}}</td>
    </ng-container>



    <tr class="example-expanded-row mat-column-name" mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr class="mat-column-name" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; let i = index; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selection.toggle(row)" [ngClass]="{'highlight2': selection.isSelected(row)}">

    </tr>
  </table>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import {SelectionModel} from '@angular/cdk/collections';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  coloredRow:any;
  selection = new SelectionModel(true, []);
  displayedColumns = ['select', 'location_id_auto', 'name_en'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  constructor(){}
  changeColor(id)
  {
    this.coloredRow = id;
  }
}

export interface Element {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {location_id_auto: 1, name_en: 'Hydrogen', },
  {location_id_auto: 2, name_en: 'Helium'},
];
```

Ive just add a selection model.